# I need to plot the data received via socket.io connection on google maps. I'm not able to figure out how?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, socket.io

I have established a server connection to get geo-tracking data. I have to plot it real time on google maps. I think that polyline is what I should use.

The following is the code for socket.io connection and data retrieval. This is the file that I load through a browser. (client.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('some-address');
    socket.on('connect', function () {
    // socket connected successfully
    console.log('socket connected successfully');

    // request for geo_history by passing the trip_id
    socket.emit('geo_history', '45');

    socket.on('geo_history', function(data) {
        // got a geo update
        console.log('geo_update received:');
        console.log(data);
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Now the map.js file is as follows:

```
function initialize() {
    var some-cen = new google.maps.LatLng('some-lat','some-lang');
    mapOptions = {
    zoom:11,
    center: some-cen,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
  styles: [{"featureType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"gamma":0.9}]}]
  };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 var coordinates = [];

 var driverPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
     path: coordinates,
 });

 driverPath.setMap(map);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

My issues:

1) The data comes in the format (as seen in the console): Object->data (Array)-> 0, 1, 2, 3..............
 And each number has its own coordinates i.e. lat and lang
How to extract only the lat and lang?
2) How to update the coordinates array so that the map updates every time a new coordinate is received?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p id="demo">Click the button to get your position.</p>

    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

    <div id="mapholder"></div>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    setInterval(function(){showPosition();},1000);
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
        latlon = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
        mapholder = document.getElementById('mapholder')
        mapholder.style.height = '250px';
        mapholder.style.width = '500px';

        var myOptions = {
        center:latlon,zoom:14,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl:false,
        navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
    }

    function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                break;
        }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: yes i tried it if you want code for displaying googlemap then tell me

Comment: Yes. I want the code. But what should I do in my code? Socket.io automatically updates the data. All I want is to be able to pass that data to the map.js file to be used by google maps.

Comment: Like I said, I am getting real-time updates for lat and lang through the socket connection. I want to draw a polyline on the map. I have 2 problems - (1) passing the object which contains the updated lat and lang to map.js and (2) plotting on the map

Comment: this will give you lat and lang every second. and you can also make it that save the previous values of lat and lang and check every second whenever condition doesn't match then pass the new values of lat and lang by obj.

Comment: But I want to use socket.io. Your method will make it useless.

Comment: sorry buddy i never used socket.io sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Thank you for trying. I figured it out after a lot of reading :)

Comment: if u find the answer then tell me too

Comment: 1) Data can be accessed by data.data[].lat and similarly for longitude
2) I called marker function whenever there was an update from server regarding the geo-data. Only marker, not initialize (which would cause the whole map to load again)